# How to fix PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 500

Tags: php, laravel

Everything is working perfectly but on running I get this error

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in htdocs\example\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php on line 500

**on line 500**

```
return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ?? null);
```

Comment: I am also getting this error while deploying in server. I am using laravel 7

Answer (score 5):

The `??` operator was introduced in php 7. You should upgrade your php version to the one required by the laravel version you are using.

Answer (score 2):

Just upgrade the php version into PHP 7.1 (ea-php71) on cpanel using  MultiPHP Manager .

Answer (score 0):

It seems your php is lower than version 7.1.3, you need to have version above that. try to run phpinfo(). Hope it helps